# Incompatible operand types int and int[]

Tags: java, arrays, int

I am working on a Java application that recognizes the weight of a phone and writes the values to a database. However I have ran into the issue where the weight int isn't compatible to the values in the array 'phoneWeight' in the if statement. I was wondering if there is a simple way to overcome this?

```
    int weight = (data[4] & 0xFF) + (data[5] << 8);
    boolean phoneOnScale = false;
    int[] phoneWeight = {140, 150};

    System.out.println("My Weight: " + weight);

    if (weight == phoneWeight) {
        phoneOnScale = true;
        System.out.println("Phone is on scale");
```

Comment: `weight == phoneWeight` is comparing a int and an array of ints. What's your intent there? That will never be true. Do you mean to check if `weight` is *in* the array?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Exactly, I want the weight that will be on the scale to be equal to whats in the array.

Comment: So, do you want to check if `weight` is itself in the array, or between the two numbers in the array like the answer is suggesting?

Comment: @Carcigenicate between the two numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`weight == phoneWeight` is attempting to compare an `int` (`weight`), and an `int[]` (`phoneWeight`). This could never be true.

If you want to check if it's between the two numbers in the array, you'd have to explicitly check for that:

```
if(phoneWeight[0] <= weight && weight <= phoneWeight[1]) {
```

Use `<` instead of `<=` if you want the bounds to be exclusive. This also assumes that the first number is the lower bound, while the second number is the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

This is an array of int's. You cannot compare an int to an array.

```
int[] phoneWeight = {140, 150};
```

You must check if weight is higher than mininum value and lower than maximum value, for phone to be on scale (between the two values), if I understood you right.